# Change the color of a grid header using Xceed Datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed-datagrid

I am using the Xceed data grid control and I am trying to change the header colors, but seem to be having some trouble. What I have right now is the following code snippet:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ColumnManagerRow));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ColumnManagerRow.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
this.grid.Resources[typeof(ColumnManagerRow)] = style;
```

This works for the most part, but I am still seeing some gray around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've added an image with the selected areas that I'd like to have as the same color.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
</Style>                

<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give me the same results?

Comment: Yes, I posted the wrong style. I've edited the answer, the style target should be `xcdg:ColumnManagerCell`.

Comment: I'm still getting the grayish borders around the cell. It does look thinner than before though.

Comment: You can create a control template and apply it to `ColumnManagerCell`s, that way you can style it more freely.

Comment: Just noticed that you updated your XAML which matches the control template that I made. However I am not able to resize the columns due to it.

Comment: I got it all setup now. Instead of a control template I made a data template. Everything works well. Thank you